# Removing duplicates from search results when searching two data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails app, I have a page that displays search results. The search covers `people` and `households`.

When `people` are displayed in the search results, their household is also displayed. If a search matches a household's address but the household is already shown in the results against a person, I only want to display the person (meaning the household is displayed once, not twice).

In Ruby, how would I compare `@results.households` and `@results.people` arrays and display a list of results in ERB that removes a `household.id` from the list if it matches a `person.household.id` that is also included in the results.

The simplified data model is as follows:

**Household**

- ID
- Address
- People

  - ID
  - Name

**Person**

- ID
- Household

  - ID
  - Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
people_household_ids = @results.people.map(&:household).compact.map(&:id)
uniq_households = @results.households.select{|hh| !people_household_ids.include?(hh.id)}
```

and in your ERB use `uniq_households` to show `households`.